# Confused why closures don't work in this JS code snippet

Tags: javascript, closures, lexical-scope

I am reading this textbook Crafting Interpreters and on Chapter 11(Resolving and Binding) this code snippet in Lox (the language we are trying to Interpret) is supposed to print "global" twice, since we want to implement closures:

```
var a = "global";
{
  fun showA() {
    print a;
  }

  showA();
  var a = "block";
  showA();
}
```

An equivalent version in JavaScript would be this:

```
var a = "global";
{
  function showA() {
    console.log(a);
  };

  showA(); // Prints "global"

  var a = "block";
  showA(); // should still print "global"
}
```

Running the javascript code prints global and then block. However I was expecting it to print 2 globals because of closure. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here.
Thank you.

Comment: `var` is not block scoped.

Comment: Also there's really nothing about the examples that has anything to do with closures.

Comment: ^ that. And due to hoisting, the code you have can *never* work the way you expect it to. Even if you change the declaration to a `let` or `const` since then you'd run into the Temporal Dead Zone.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed this was about closures because the textbook said, "If you’re familiar with closures in other languages, you’ll expect it to print “global” twice". And after looking into it, I understand why it should print global twice, but I'm confused why it does not print global twice in the js version.

Comment: Because there is no closure here. It prints *the same* variable `a` twice. The variable changes between the prints. No magic, no nothing. You just expect a lot more from this piece of code than it actually does.

Comment: In JS, scopes are static (ignoring `eval`). When a scope is entered, all its variables are already known. `var a` does not "add" a new variable to the scope when the line is executed.